# Pass a function as parameter when invoking JS function from C# code

Tags: javascript, c#, silverlight

I have a Silverlight app which should call a Javascript function and pass a callback-function as parameter. The JS-code for doing this would look like this:

```
var myobject = new MyCoolObject();    
myobject.doSomethingAsync(function(result) { /* do something with the result */ });
```

In C# I have the following code:

```
var myobject = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance("MyCoolObject");
myobject.Invoke("doSomethingAsync", new Action<object>(this.FunctionCallback));
```

But C# method 'FunctionCallback' is never called. Instead I get an error message 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

Comment: I am sorry that you have to use Silverlight :\